# How to multiply to each value in each element in SArray in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, graphlab

I'm using Graphlab, but I guess this question can apply to pandas.

```
import graphlab
sf = graphlab.SFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'user_score': [{"a":4, "b":3}, {"a":5, "b":7}, {"a":2, "b":3}], 'weight': [4, 5, 2]})
```

I want to create a new column where the value of each element in 'user_score' is multiplied by the number in 'weight'. That is,

```
sf = graphlab.SFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'user_score': [{"a":4, "b":3}, {"a":5, "b":7}, {"a":2, "b":3}], 'weight': [4, 5, 2]}, 'new':[{"a":16, "b":12}, {"a":25, "b":35}, {"a":4, "b":6}])
```

I tried to write a simple function below and applied to no avail. Any thoughts?

```
def trans(x, y):
    d = dict()
    for k, v in x.items():
        d[k] = v*y
    return d

sf.apply(trans(sf['user_score'], sf['weight']))
```

It got the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'SArray' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is subtle, but I think what you want is this:

```
sf.apply(lambda row: trans(row['user_score'], row['weight']))
```

The apply function takes a function as its argument, and will pass each row as the parameter to that function. In your version, you are evaluating the trans function before apply is called, which is why the error message complains about passing an SArray to the trans function when a dict is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `pandas` dataframe, but it should also work in your case.

```
import pandas as pd
df['new']=[dict((k,v*y) for k,v in x.items()) for x, y in zip(df['user_score'], df['weight'])]
```

**Input dataframe:**

```
df
Out[34]: 
   id          user_score  weight
0   1  {u'a': 4, u'b': 3}       4
1   2  {u'a': 5, u'b': 7}       5
2   3  {u'a': 2, u'b': 3}       2
```

**Output:**

```
df
Out[36]: 
   id          user_score  weight                   new
0   1  {u'a': 4, u'b': 3}       4  {u'a': 16, u'b': 12}
1   2  {u'a': 5, u'b': 7}       5  {u'a': 25, u'b': 35}
2   3  {u'a': 2, u'b': 3}       2    {u'a': 4, u'b': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one of many possible solutions:

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]:
   id        user_score  weight
0   1  {'b': 3, 'a': 4}       4
1   2  {'b': 7, 'a': 5}       5
2   3  {'b': 3, 'a': 2}       2

In [70]: df['user_score'] = df['user_score'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).mul(df.weight, axis=0).to_dict('record')

In [71]: df
Out[71]:
   id          user_score  weight
0   1  {'b': 12, 'a': 16}       4
1   2  {'b': 35, 'a': 25}       5
2   3    {'b': 6, 'a': 4}       2
```

Comment: apply means it is NOT vectorized by definition

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for your comment! I've corrected my answer

Comment: @Jeff, please correct me if i'm wrong, but i think something like `df['num_column'].apply(np.sum)` - IS vectorized, because it'll be applied on the whole column (not element-by-element) - or do i understand it wrong?

Comment: yes if you pass a *ufunc* (which ``np.sum``) it will be executed as-if ``np.sum(df['num_columns'])``, so that is 'vectorized'. The point is almost always ``.apply`` is NOT vectorized. (and hence has a perf penalty compared to almost anything else).